# how to add or modify chromecast whitelist URLs

Tags: chromecast

Suppose I want to change the URLs that I supplied when I first whitelisted the chromecast. What should I do?  Use the same whitelisting request page as I used initially?

e.g. https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1E-vka5QP8LkF0nbfz-omN1DjNSX1uLGyqHdbpEFh6zg/viewform

Will it be another 4-5 business days for that request to be approved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not done already, use the same URL that you used before and ask for an update to your URL. It hopefully won't take long.